# How to perform simple map reduce in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am using trigrams for full-text search in postgres like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Users" users 
WHERE 'search_text' % ANY(regexp_split_to_array(users.name,E'\\s+'))
```

Query above checks if `search_text` matches any word (split by `whitespace`) in `User.displayName`. This works however results are not ordered by actual "score".

Score can be calculated by `similarity(text,text)` function.

The problem is that I have to order by them sum of all similarities found for each word in `User.name`. So if user name is `"A B C"` then its score should be:

```
similarity('search_text','A') + similarity('search_text','B') + similarity('search_text','C')
```

So I need to map user name words to scores and then sum (reduce) them. How I can do this in postgres?

Answer (score 4):

In instead of splitting to an array split to a set then regroup summing the similarity

```
with users as (
    select user_id, name
    from (values (1, 'John Smith')) t(user_id, name)
)
select user_id, sum(similarity('smth', name_part))
from (
    select user_id, regexp_split_to_table(name, E'\\s+') as name_part
    from users
) users
where 'smth' % name_part
group by user_id
order by 2 desc
;
 user_id |  sum  
---------+-------
       1 | 0.375
```

I'm not sure you want to eliminate those name parts for which the similarity is lower than the threshold. If not just omit the `where` clause

BTW, why do you need to split the name? Why not just compare the whole name to the search string?

```
with users as (
    select user_id, name
    from (values (1, 'John Smith')) t(user_id, name)
)
select similarity('jon smth', name), *
from users
order by 1 desc
;
 similarity | user_id |    name    
------------+---------+------------
   0.333333 |       1 | John Smith
```